# Couchbase's Startkey and endKey in the node.js SDK

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, mapreduce, couchbase

[Docs on view querying](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Views/views-querying.html)

`startKey` and `endKey` are useful to find ranges of keys. After [scouring the documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-node-client-2.0.0/Bucket.html#query), I can't find any mention of them in the node.js SDK 2.0

How do I specify `startKey` and `endKey` when creating `ViewQuery` requests? Do they pass as the mysterious "options" param in `Bucket#query`?

In other words, I'm not exactly clear on how to run a query on a view if I only want a certain subset of that view. If a view indexes a million documents and I don't know it by name, is there a way to find it by type, or do I have to have an entirely separate view that only indexes by type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ViewQuery` object has a method called `range`, which lets you specify the start and end keys. It's not in the current documentation for some reason, but you can see the method definition in the client source code:

```
ViewQuery.prototype.range = function(start, end, inclusive_end) {
  this.options.startkey = JSON.stringify(start);
  this.options.endkey = JSON.stringify(end);
  if (inclusive_end) {
    this.options.inclusive_end = 'true';
  } else {
    delete this.options.inclusive_end;
  }
  return this;
};
```